How to swap first and last pane in tmux?
My .tmux.conf currently has the following keybind to achieve swapping the first and last panes
bind-key BSpace swap-pane -s1 -t3

This works great when I only have 3 panes, but doesn't identify the last pane in other cases.
How can I replace 3 with the max pane value?
tmux list-panes -F "#P" | tail -n 1 gives the last pane number, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the resulting value into a command.

bind-key BSpace swap-pane -s :.1 -t :.-
